# mdadm - setting faulty device doesn't result in new mail in the root mailbox

Tags: raid, mdadm, mail

If I understand correctly, mdadm is supposed to mail root when something fails because it has

```
MAILADDR root
```

in mdadm.conf

But

```
sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --set-faulty /dev/sdb1
```

and then

```
sudo mail
```

results in no new mail at all.

What part am I getting wrong ?
Thanks!

EDIT: Eeeeh, it not really Ubuntu '-_-, it's Raspbian, kernel 4.9.59

```
pi@oukspi:~ $ ps aux | grep mdadm
pi       16028  0.0  0.0   4372   556 pts/0    S+   18:31   0:00 grep --color=auto mdadm
root     28455  0.0  0.1   2560  1800 ?        Ss   12:03   0:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan
root     28469  0.0  0.1   2560  1640 ?        Ss   12:04   0:00 mdadm --monitor --daemonise /dev/md0
```

Comment: Is `mdadm` running in *monitor* mode? You can check that with `ps aux | grep mdadm`. You also might want to add the output of this command to your question if there is output. Please also add the Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: Answered in Edit of the original post.